# Formatting diff output to show "current - values previous - values"

Tags: bash, shell, sed, diff

I have a ***for*** loop that determines if there are any differences between two files. If there are differences, I need to append those differences to a text file that I will then email to certain colleagues.

I'm currently trying to use ***diff -y*** so the output of the command and the resulting email will have an easy to read format for the recipients.

the command I'm using to get the raw differences is this:

`diff -y unita3x0101.pre unita3x0101.pre.v1 | grep "|" >> filetoemail.txt`

Which gives me the following output:

```
command=(PV SY 102) - PV SY 102  7:54:38                      | command=(PV SY 102) - PV SY 102  7:27:47
command=(PV SY 906) - PV SY 906 2600.000 Inj#1 K-Fact         | command=(PV SY 906) - PV SY 906 5200.000 Inj#1 K-Fact
command=(PV SY 907) - PV SY 907 0.8424 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact         | command=(PV SY 907) - PV SY 907 0.9600 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact
command=(PV SY 912) - PV SY 912 0.1560 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact         | command=(PV SY 912) - PV SY 912 1.3109 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
Current - PV SY 102  7:54:38                      Previous - PV SY 102  7:27:47
Current - PV SY 906 2600.000 Inj#1 K-Fact         Previous - PV SY 906 5200.000 Inj#1 K-Fact
Current - PV SY 907 0.8424 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact         Previous - PV SY 907 0.9600 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact
Current - PV SY 912 0.1560 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact         Previous - PV SY 912 1.3109 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact
```

The closest I got to my desired output was by using this:

`diff -y unita3x0101.pre unita3x0101.pre.v1 | grep "|" | sed s/\command=\(PV/Current\ \ / | sed s/\command=\(PV/Previous\ \ /`

But it doesn't remove all the unwanted characters:

```
Current   SY 102) - PV SY 102  7:54:38                        | Previous   SY 102) - PV SY 102  7:27:47
Current   SY 906) - PV SY 906 2600.000 Inj#1 K-Fact           | Previous   SY 906) - PV SY 906 5200.000 Inj#1 K-Fact
Current   SY 907) - PV SY 907 0.8424 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact           | Previous   SY 907) - PV SY 907 0.9600 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact
Current   SY 912) - PV SY 912 0.1560 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact           | Previous   SY 912) - PV SY 912 1.3109 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact
```

Is there another way, or more sed commands I can add/use to make the output more 'user friendly'?

Comment: Perl or awk could accomplish this task easier than sed.

Comment: Thats what I needed! using awk -F '[)|]' and printing "Current $2 Previous $4" gives me what I need. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe `diff` to this `awk` command and avoid `grep`:

```
diff -y unita3x0101.pre unita3x0101.pre.v1 |
awk -F ' - |[[:blank:]]*\\|' '/[|]/{printf "%-40s\t\t%-40s\n",
       "Current - " $2, "Previous - " $4}'

Current - PV SY 102  7:54:38                    Previous - PV SY 102  7:27:47
Current - PV SY 906 2600.000 Inj#1 K-Fact       Previous - PV SY 906 5200.000 Inj#1 K-Fact
Current - PV SY 907 0.8424 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact       Previous - PV SY 907 0.9600 Inj#1 Mtr-Fact
Current - PV SY 912 0.1560 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact       Previous - PV SY 912 1.3109 Inj#2 Mtr-Fact
```